# ZMQ script - send only one message and wait for full reply

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq

I'm having problems with python script, which is used to control game server ( **Quakelive**) via **`rcon`** ( you can send commands and they are executed on server - like changing map or password ).

Game developers provided such script. It is written using **`ZeroMQ`** library, however the problem is it takes commands from standard input ( first they go to queue and then are sent to server ) and when there are no commands in **`stdin`**, it just waits for them.

And what I would like to make is send / execute only one command, finish connection and 'go further', however I'm pretty new to python and `ZeroMQ`, so I'm kinda lost.

This is that script: https://github.com/marconett/quakelive-docker/blob/master/zmq_rcon.py.

Also, what I deduced from testing, server needs to send full reply <sub>( sometimes it's 2 lines, sometimes 10 )</sub> otherwise it gets suspended.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes.
<sub>In `ZeroMQ` reply is needed for a `REQ/REP` formal pattern.</sub>

First, let's demystify the problem.

`ZeroMQ` is a lovely piece of code. It's **S**caleable **F**ormal **C**ommunication **P**attern name somehow resembles what is going on, if respective counterparties strive to use such formal behaviour.

Having taken from line 114, **`REP/REP`** is being used, where **`REQ`** asks and **`REP`** has to answer ( and `REQ`-side has to receive / "read" it ), before **`REQ`** can send another request-message to the `REP`-side:

```
    ...
    server_rep = server_ctx.socket( zmq.REP )        # ____________.REP archetype
    server_rep.bind( HOST )                          #                ^ |
    ...                                              #                | v
    client_socket_1 = client_ctx_1.socket( zmq.REQ ) # ____________.REQ archetype
    client_socket_1.connect( HOST )
    ...
    client_socket_2 = client_ctx_2.socket( zmq.REQ ) # ____________.REQ archetype
    client_socket_2.connect( HOST )
```

So, irrespective, whether the initial source-data, that are going to be sent to the **`REP`**, came from `stdin`, from a `fileIO` `.readline()` or from another `ZeroMQ`-pattern socket-endpoint, each **`REQ`**-message has to get re-unlocked by a **`REP`**-message ( on the RPC-**remote**-side, than your code strives to just send one command the server and quit ).

So, the server-side code is responsible for well-designed code, not your one.